# Animate CSS generated :after content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to add an animation to the content generated with CSS when you hover over it. Currently it just pops up, but I want it to slide in from left to right. I tried to add a transition but it still doesn't do anything. If it's not possible in CSS can I do it in jquery?

Here is a fiddle of what the code is doing now: http://jsfiddle.net/35mtB/

---

HTML:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Petit+Formal+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="logo">
          <h1>&lt;/</h1><h1 id="text">Ja</h1><h1>&gt;</h1>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

---

CSS:

```
   <style>
     #logo {
       display:flex;
       align-items:center;
       width:100%;
       height:300px;
       border:2px solid #000;
     }

     h1:hover {
       cursor:pointer;
     }

     h1 {
       text-align:center;
       display:inline-block;
       font-size:50px;
       font-family:'Petit Formal Script';
       text-shadow: 0.02em 0.02em #FFFFFF,  0.05em 0.05em #33cc99;
     }

     #text:before {
       content:"";
     }

     #text:hover:after {
       content:"Wapa";
       -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
       transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
     }
   </style>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this in CSS without jQuery or even JavaScript.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8mp4/1/ This should get you started.

Comment: @TylerH - That is not even close to what he wants.  Note the :after text "Wapa" which you've completely ignored.  He wants the "Wapa" to slide in, presumably from behind "Ja".

Comment: @Michael Notice how I'm just getting him started with how to move elements. I stripped out irrelevant code. Also notice how it is a comment and not an answer. It is exactly what he wants in that it is the first step to getting what he wants.

Comment: @TylerH - Yes, that was a good start to what I wanted. I worked with it a little bit and got is pretty close. Thanks!

Michael - Yes, I wanted it to slide in from the Ja.

Comment: @JaWapa - Getting it to animate from behind the Ja is going to be a bit more difficult, lots of masking will be needed.  Definitely easier to do with a more versatile HTML setup though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a reformat of your HTML to do this easier.  You are close to animating the :after text you were using, but I was having issues with fine control of the text.  Animating a box after "Ja" is easy, but the text is trickier.

To that extent.. A reformat of the HTML will make your HTML more semantic when it comes to SEO, especially considering the text is contained inside an H1.

Consider using this as your HTML code, it is semantically better for SEO, and IMHO easier to handle with CSS.

```
<h1 id="text">&lt;/<span class="ja">Ja</span><span class="wapa">Wapa</span>&gt;</h1>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35mtB/8/)

```
h1 span.wapa {
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate3d(-250px, 0px, 0px);    
    -webkit-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
}

h1 span.ja:hover + span.wapa {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); 
}
```

Comment: The slide animation is exactly what I'm looking for, but how can I animate the width change. I tried to add a transition time but it didn't help with that, it only slowed the slide in time.

Comment: @JaWapa - Two things are required to achieve that.  First, is to change the transition property to specify that the transition should apply to more than just the transform.  You could do this specifically by telling it to transition the width and the transform properties, or just use "all".  The JD Fiddle below uses the two separate properties.  The second requirement, is to change the "auto" width to a specific width.  Auto is not able to be transformed.  I used a value of 130px.

Note that this JSFiddle is missing prefixes for transition property. http://jsfiddle.net/35mtB/10/

Comment: Thank you! I figured out that I needed an exact width and then could apply "transition:all 1s", then it would work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually animating anything in your code.

```
#text:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate3d(-250px, 0px, 0px);
}

 #text:hover:after {
   content:"Wapa";
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);    
   -webkit-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFcEV/) with the basics outlined. You can customise it to suit your needs.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted! Thank you... I'll have to work with the timing and animation a little bit, but this will work! Thank you!

Comment: @JaWapa - Note that your HTML markup is semantically "bad" for SEO.  See below for an exact duplicate of this functionality with better HTML.  (also more flexibility for control of how the > animates.